# SFML "Unresolved external token" while linking statically and dynamically

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sfml

I want to program low-level games, for which I need SFML. So I followed this tutorial: https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-vc.php

When I used the debug versions of the libraries and used dll's (which I placed in the folder of my source code) for debug build mode, It threw the following linking errors at me:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sf::String::String(char const *,class std::locale const &)" (__imp_??0String@sf@@QAE@PBDABVlocale@std@@@Z) referenced in function _main    SFML-Example    C:\Users\wout\source\repos\SFML-Example\SFML-Example\SFML-Example.obj   1
    
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sf::String::~String(void)" (__imp_??1String@sf@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main   SFML-Example    C:\Users\wout\source\repos\SFML-Example\SFML-Example\SFML-Example.obj   1   

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(class sf::VideoMode,class sf::String const &,unsigned int,struct sf::ContextSettings const &)" (__imp_??0RenderWindow@sf@@QAE@VVideoMode@1@ABVString@1@IABUContextSettings@1@@Z) referenced in function _main   SFML-Example    C:\Users\wout\source\repos\SFML-Example\SFML-Example\SFML-Example.obj   1

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow(void)" (__imp_??1RenderWindow@sf@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function _main SFML-Example    C:\Users\wout\source\repos\SFML-Example\SFML-Example\SFML-Example.obj   1
    
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class sf::VideoMode __cdecl sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode(void)" (__imp_?getDesktopMode@VideoMode@sf@@SA?AV12@XZ) referenced in function _main SFML-Example    C:\Users\wout\source\repos\SFML-Example\SFML-Example\SFML-Example.obj   1
```

When I used the static versions of the libraries (with -s extension) and defined SFML_STATIC for release build mode, it threw these errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall sf::String::String(char const *,class std::locale const &)" (??0String@sf@@QAE@PBDABVlocale@std@@@Z) SFML-Example    C:\Users\wout\source\repos\SFML-Example\SFML-Example\SFML-Example.obj   1   

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(class sf::VideoMode,class sf::String const &,unsigned int,struct sf::ContextSettings const &)" (??0RenderWindow@sf@@QAE@VVideoMode@1@ABVString@1@IABUContextSettings@1@@Z)    SFML-Example    C:\Users\wout\source\repos\SFML-Example\SFML-Example\SFML-Example.obj   1   

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow(void)" (??1RenderWindow@sf@@UAE@XZ)  SFML-Example    C:\Users\wout\source\repos\SFML-Example\SFML-Example\SFML-Example.obj   1

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: static class sf::VideoMode __cdecl sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode(void)" (?getDesktopMode@VideoMode@sf@@SA?AV12@XZ)  SFML-Example    C:\Users\wout\source\repos\SFML-Example\SFML-Example\SFML-Example.obj   1
```

In my Project Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies I have the following:

```
winmm.lib
opengl32.lib
freetype.lib
gdi32.lib
openal32.lib
flac.lib
vorbisenc.lib
vorbisfile.lib
vorbis.lib
ogg.lib
ws2_32.lib
sfml-graphics-s.lib
sfml-window-s.lib
sfml-system-s.lib
sfml-audio-s.lib
sfml-network-s.lib
```

Edit:
When I run DUMPBIN /EXPORTS sfml-system.lib, I see that String::String is defined, though I get a linking error which says it isn't:

```
 ??0String@sf@@QEAA@DAEBVlocale@std@@@Z (public: __cdecl sf::String::String(char,class std::locale const &))
                  ??0String@sf@@QEAA@I@Z (public: __cdecl sf::String::String(unsigned int))
                  ??0String@sf@@QEAA@PEBDAEBVlocale@std@@@Z (public: __cdecl sf::String::String(char const *,class std::locale const &))
                  ??0String@sf@@QEAA@PEBI@Z (public: __cdecl sf::String::String(unsigned int const *))
                  ??0String@sf@@QEAA@PEB_W@Z (public: __cdecl sf::String::String(wchar_t const *))
                  ??0String@sf@@QEAA@XZ (public: __cdecl sf::String::String(void))
                  ??0String@sf@@QEAA@_W@Z (public: __cdecl sf::String::String(wchar_t
```

Edit:
After I ran DUMPBIN /headers *.lib | findstr machine, I found out every library is 64-bit.

Any help and insight is appreciated!

Comment: Run `DUMPBIN /EXPORTS sfml-system.lib` and/or `DUMPBIN /SYMBOLS sfml-system-s.lib` to  see which symbols are provided. Is there `sf::String::String` in there somewhere?

Comment: Yes, it is defined: look at the edit.

Comment: Are you building a 64 bit executable? Are your libraries 64 bit?

Comment: I am assuming the libraries I am using are 32-bit, but I build for x86-bit architecture.

Comment: The ***LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport)*** errors mean it's expecting you to link to an import library that goes along with a dll which will be used at runtime.

Comment: I believe the _s.lib files are static libraries which are not import libraries. I think your issue is you need to configure sfml to tell it you want to use static libraries. Not sure how to do that.

Comment: I believe that at runtime, the process will look into the cwd and use the dll's I placed in there, That's what the tutorial told me atleast. When I define the macro SFML_STATIC it will be compiled as static and it wont look into these dll's.

Comment: Assume nothing, check everything. If your active configuration is Win32, you need 32 bit libraries. If your active configuration is x86_64, you need 64 bit libraries.

Comment: SUCCESS!!! there was a MACRO in the external lib that was adding the dllimport. removing it and fixed the build. Thansk so much everyone for the guidance